# Using previous_changes in after_save callback with rails_admin

Tags: rails-admin

I have an after_save callback that uses the previous_changes method to test for field change.  It works fine when I save a record in rails console, but fails to recognise that the field has changed  when I try to trigger it in rails_admin.

```
  def mailers
  if previous_changes['pending_approval'] == [false, true]
    ProjectMailer.project_owner_new_project(self).deliver_later
    Rails.logger.debug("Changed Pending to False!!".green)
  end
  Rails.logger.debug("hit project mailer callback".red)
end
```

In this example, when run in console (with a record that has just changed pending_approval from true to false) I get two logged messages; "changed pending to False!!" and "hit project mailer callback"

When I change the state in rails_admin, I only get the second "hit project mailer callback." This leads me to believe that rails_admin is doing something that interferes with the Dirty class handling of my record.  Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to change the after callback to before and use self_attribute_changed?(from: true, to: false) like this:

```
  def mailers
    if self.pending_approval_changed?(from: true, to: false)
      ProjectMailer.project_owner_new_project(self).deliver_later
      Rails.logger.debug("Changed Pending to False!!".green)
    end
    Rails.logger.debug("hit project mailer callback".red)
  end
```

I suppose another way that would utilize the same strategy would be to use the around_save like so

```
  def mailers
    changed = self.pending_approval.changed?(from: true, to: false)
    yield
    if changed
      ProjectMailer.project_owner_new_project(self).deliver_later
      Rails.logger.debug("Changed Pending to False!!".green)
    end
    Rails.logger.debug("hit project mailer callback".red)
  end
```

I tried the first way and it worked well for my situation. Haven't tested the second way.